# have object in custom class be seen in my viewcontroller, trying to create locationManager with CLGeocoder

Tags: ios

Good Afternoon All,

I am trying to complete the tutorials on locationManager and CLGeocoder but am having trouble understanding how these can interact with one another through classes.

To explain, I followed a tutorial to show current location which works.  Now I am trying to have CLGeocoder return information on that location, but I am having trouble since locationManager is in a different class.  My problem is understanding custom classes and how view controller ties it all together.

Here is my code so far.

appdelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LocationGetter.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LocationGetter.h"

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (retain, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (retain, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *lastKnownLocation;


@end
```

appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:       (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController"     bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.locationGetter = [[LocationGetter alloc] init];
    self.locationGetter.delegate = self;
    [self.locationGetter startUpdates];
```

class locationgetter.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@protocol LocationGetterDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) newPhysicalLocation:(CLLocation *)location;
@end

@interface LocationGetter : NSObject

-(void)startUpdates;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<LocationGetterDelegate>delegate;



@end
```

locationgetter.m

```
#import "LocationGetter.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface LocationGetter () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end

@implementation LocationGetter
//@synthesize geoCoder;


bool didUpdate = NO;

-(void) startUpdates{
    NSLog(@"Starting Location Updates");

    if (self.locationManager == nil)
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];



}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your location could not be determined." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}

// Delegate method from the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol.
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (didUpdate)
        return;

    didUpdate = YES;
    // Disable future updates to save power.
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];

    // let our delegate know we're done
    [_delegate newPhysicalLocation:newLocation];

}



@end
```

Now here is the problem...

somewhere I need to put in an CLGeocoder property, and an action from a button that launches the CLGeocoder.
I tried putting this in view controller

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet CLGeocoder *geoCoder;

- (IBAction)geoCodeLocation:(id)sender;
```

and this in viewcontroller.m

```
- (IBAction)geoCodeLocation:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"hello %@,", sender); 
[self.geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation: locationManager.location completionHandler: 
 ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
}
```

but the way I have it, locationManager is not found.  I guess because location is found in AppDelegate.M.  This is my problem, I do not understand how I can have location to be seen once I'm in the viewcontroller.  I come from a c# background where I would just pass a variable, or make a global variable.

Can someone please explain the best way to communication the objects in IOS.
Please let me know if I need to explain myself better.

THanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your requirements are, but if you only need to do location stuff in one view controller in your app, I'd dispense with the `LocationGetter` and `LocationGetterDelegate` classes and have the `CLLocationManager` as an ivar of `ViewController` and just implement the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` methods in `ViewController`.

If you do it this way you eliminate the problem of getting access to the `CLLocationManager` in the app delegate, so you can do:

```
[self.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation: self.locationManager.location completionHandler: 
^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) { //completion stuff
}];
```

Apple do this in their 'GeocoderDemo' demo project, available [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GeocoderDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011097) - in fact they have a different `CLLocationManager` instance in each tab VC! (3 instances). I understand that your way is slightly cleaner and more elegant- but for the average app it's probably overkill. Simpler is generally better.

That said, if you absolutely must have the `CLLocationManager` in the app delegate, wrapped in your custom classes, you could change your method in `ViewController.m` to

```
- (IBAction)geoCodeLocation:(id)sender 
{
   AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
   //probably want some error handling here to deal with possibility that 
   //delegate.lastKnownLocation is nil.
   [self.geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation: delegate.lastKnownLocation completionHandler: 
   ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        //completion stuff
   }];
}
```

(You'll obviously need to `#import "AppDelegate.h"` in any class you do this in).

Minor points:

-There's no point in making the `CLGeocoder` an `IBOutlet`, since it isn't a UI element.

-You are `#import` ing `UIKit` and `LocationGetter` twice in your app delegate.(I realize this might be a typo!).

Comment: You are correct in that it is not actually needed to put cllocation manager in a separate class, however I am trying to learn am much as possible about ios and I feel this is a good learning exercise.   Therefore can you please tell me how to make locationgetter a property of app delegate. I see you'd example code,  but where do I actually put those two lines.   Thanks for the minor points.  I'll fix those as well

Comment: Rereading your code I see you don't actually need to expose `LocationGetter` at all - I'm assuming AppDelegate has an implementation of the `LocationGetterDelegate` protocol method which sets the delegate's `lastKnownLocation` property to the location passed in. I've amended my answer accordingly. I still think it's a bit of a complicated way to do it, but hey.

Comment: thanks.... I took your advice and I decided to keep it simple and get everything working in viewcontroller.  Once I have a better foundation of objective-c then I'll start using custom classes.  appreciate the help!!